# Can't install Compare plugin in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I am trying to install compare plugin in notepad++ **v7.6.2** 32bit

following this tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qvEOX6mSbpo

I did exact same steps, except I realized when I tried to place the DLL in the plugins folder, I didn't find a plugins folder!

so I created one myself and placed the DLL. restarted notepad++ and I can't see the compare plugin at all in plugins

[image: plugins]

I found this thread here

https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/17492/plugins-gone/2

apparently, plugins in the new version have to be placed in a subfolder of the plugin name due to organization

so I did that, and still, I can't see the compare plugin

[image: ComparePlgin]

finally, I tried installing from PluginsAdmin (apparently that's what plugin manager is replaced within new notepad++ versions), and it restarts automatically during installation, but i still cannot see compare plugin listed...

[image: pluginAdmin]

what is going on?

**Update:**

i discovered, thanks to [this thread](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/16752/cannot-get-compare-plugin-to-load/12) (last post) that based on initial installation selection (which i think i just did default installation whatever options are selected automatically), i found the plugins folder in `%APPDATA%`

[image: appdata]

still, placing the dll there didn't help. the plugin won't show up still!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Finally! I figured out why thanks to this post here:

https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/17276/cannot-install-plugins-at-all/11

because my machine is company machine, it appears the proxy must be set

[image: proxy]

Do this in elevated mode (i.e. open notepad++ as administrator)

after that, from pluginAdmin,

[image: plugins admin]

install compare plugin, restarted notepad++, and wala! the plugin is showing up finally!!

Comment: @NPS I didnt expect this to gain this much traction. Its awesome to see my post is helping many others with this issue!

Answer (score 2):

Or another fix is to disconnect from your company intranet, connect to the internet via wifi or using your mobile phone usb tethering. Then try to install the plugin, it will work. It's because np++ domain is blocked by your network administrator

Comment: It was the problem for me!